# Ubuntu - Ethernet Card Driver Installation: asm/linkage.h file not found

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, ethernet

I'm trying to install an Ethernet Card into my ubuntu 14.04 desktop computer.
Here is my `lspci` output (Second one is my new ethernet card):

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8053 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6120/VT6121/VT6122 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter (rev 82)
```

I found its driver on this link: https://driverscollection.com/?file_cid=4033090637401388678a544c5d6. And when I tried to install it, I get this error:

```
fatal error: asm/linkage.h: No such file or directory
```

I noticed that this driver supports Linux AMD64 Kernel between 2.4.x ~ 2.6.18, but my kernel version is `3.13.0-57-generic`. I have searched all over the web for this problem but I could not find any working solution related to this. Without changing my current kernel version any successions, what can fix the problem?

I have already installed the linux kernel headers.

Comment: have you installed the kernel headers?

Comment: Have you checked (e.g using `modinfo via-velocity`) that you don't already have a suitable driver already available?  If not, it may be better to rebuild your kernel with it available (that's usually safer than using vendor-provided device drivers).